# Can PHP be used to set XY, zoom of Mapbox.js map

Tags: javascript, mapbox, php

Is there a way to set the xy and zoom level of a map using the URL of the site that is calling it?

I'm thinking of a site I'm using now, built on php, which has mapbox maps built in javascript and added to a DIV.

I am hoping to use something like:

> http: //mysite.com/map.php?x=234.534&y=34323.2343&zoom=5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using mapbox.js directly, you can call `map.ui.hash.add()` (assuming your map variable is named `map`), and the page will have a hash like `#10.00/45.5342/-73.7457` which encodes the zoom level, latitude, and longitude of the map position, and you can send users to URLs like that to set the initial map position.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a code snippet I found online that parses PHP URL variables into JavaScript. You may have to modify it a little to fit your needs, but it's pretty short and simple:

http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/